# How to specify install dependencies for go get

Tags: go, dependency-management

I can specify dependencies to be downloaded by `go get` after checking out my project by importing them. I can even force the download of packages that are not used in the code by importing them for side effects:

`import _ "github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata"`

Furthermore, on the shell I can apparently *install* a program with `go get` by using an ellipsis after the path:

```
$ go get github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/...
```

However, it seems I cannot combine both techniques:

`import _ "github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata/..."`

```
$ go get
main.go:9:8: open c:\gopath\src\github.com\jteeuwen\go-bindata\...: Access denied
```

I would like to tell `go get` that for building (actually `go generate`ing) this project, [`go-bindata`](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) has to be *installed*. Is it possible to specify install-dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: No.

But you could vendor go-bindata into your project which would make it available after after `go get`ing your project.

But maybe there is a slight confusion about when and why to run `go generate`: The intended use for `go generate` (as I understand it) is for package or command *authors* to generate code during the development phase. Code which is checked in and processed "normally" by `go {build,install,get}`. So *you* run `go generate`, check in the generated stuff and users of your package `go get` it and do *not* run go generate. They don't need to, the code comes in the proper checked in version during `get`ing.

For more complicated builds which a end-user has to perform: Use Makefiles or similar tools as such stuff is out of the scope of `go get`.

Comment: Wouldn't that mean having all the assets twice, once encoded and once original?

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects I use [Godep](https://github.com/tools/godep). According to its page:

> This tool assumes you are working in a standard Go workspace, as
>   described in http://golang.org/doc/code.html. We expect godep to build
>   on Go 1.4* or newer, but you can use it on any project that works with
>   Go 1 or newer.

You'll have your dependencies in a JSON file, just like Node, Bower, etc... It's vert simple to use.

In your case, assuming you already have `go get`ed the package, run:

```
godep save
```

This will generate the JSON file with all your other dependencies and save to a folder in your project. Thanks to it I was capable of cross compiling my project.